# Youtube feed limit results

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to create a Youtube feed reader using `https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id={CHANNEL:ID}`, everything works but I want to read only one or two entries.

Is this possible to limit these feeds to return only a concrete number of entries? I don't want to use the V3 api as it will restrict the number of calls per day.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old-fashion way of limiting/paginating results of feeds have been depracated long ago and tourned off since 2015 along with YouTube Data API v2.

https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=XXXXX is still on but fixed (and limited) to 15 results.

So, one of the two:
- migrate to YouTube Data API (v3)
or
- parsing yourself the feed server side (PHP or whatever) to get only the first one/two results.

sadly, no other way.

Comment: That's what I supposed. Pitiful. I don't want to use Data API V3 because the credit limit, I suppose will stick to the feed and cut the requests manually.

Comment: The link you've provide is down